# How can I use Apache RewriteRules + PHP to determine which page to show?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

I am trying to make a scalable RewriteRule on my .htaccess, I use each word before slash as a parameter.

for example: `http://localhost/mysite/param1/param2/param3/.../param20`

I am working with this code (but if I want 6 o 7 parameters, it would be too long):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine   on

DirectoryIndex  web.php?param1=inicio

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$                      web.php?param1=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$     web.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```

Next rewriteRules would be longer `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ web.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5`

I send each parameter to php as an indivudal variable, and I use the first parameter to decide wich page must be shown on web.php. Is there any way to make it shorten? I don't know how to optimize it. I don't even know if I am on the right way. How would you make it? Maybe using php? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do parameter parsing within a RewriteRule, except if you have a small fixed number of parameters (like MediaWiki [does](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL)).

Instead, redirect every request (or a subset of them based on the first characters of the URL for example) to a PHP script which will do the parsing of the URL itself. It would then display the correct page based on what it parsed.